# Arbitrary base change of a parahoric subgroup in split case

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, local-fields, buildings

Assume $R\subset R'$ are henselien discretly valued rings with fraction field $K$ and $K'$, $G$ is a semisimple split group over $K$. Consider the parahoric group scheme $\mathcal{P}_F$ over $R$ associated to a facet $F$ in the Bruhat-Tits building of $G$.

Is it true that the base change $\mathcal{P}_F\times_R R'$ still a parahoric group scheme of $G\times_K K'$?

Is the group $\mathcal{P}_F(R')$ a parahoric subgroup of $G(K')$ associated to the same facet $F$?

Comment: This is true when the extension $K'/K$ is unramified. When $K'/K$ is ramified, this is not true in general. Moreover, in that case,  this does not make sense to consider the parahoric subgroup of $G(K')$ associated to the same facet, since the inclusion "building over $K$" $\subset$ "building over $K'$" is not simplicial.

Comment: For the case $K'/K$ unramified you can refer to Bruhat-Tits IHES. For a counter-example when $K'/K$ is ramified, you can consider the base change of an Iwahori subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,K)$.

Comment: But now the group $G$ is split, I guess $G$ and $G\times K'$ has the same apartments?

Comment: and by the way, is it true that $\mathcal{P}_F(R')$ always contains a  parahoric subgroup of $G(K')$?

Comment: Yes any apartment of $G$ is an apartment of $G\times K'$ (but of course the converse is false).  When $G={\rm SL}(2)$, $K'/K$ quadratic ramified,  and $F$ is a chamber, then ${\mathcal P}_F (K')$ fixes two chambers and therefore cannot contain a parahoric subgroup of $G(K')$.